# Using recursion to get the deeply nested struct in go

Tags: recursion, go, types

I need to parse an interface read from a JSON object which is deeply nested. I use the following recursive function to get most of the array.

```
func arrayReturn(m map[string]interface{}) []interface{} {
    for _, v:= range m {
        if v.(type) == map[string]interface{} {
            return arrayReturn(v.(map[string]interface{}))
        }
        if v.(type) == string {
            return v.([]interface{})
        } 
    }
}
```

Which gives this error for the `return` line:

```
syntax error: unexpected return, expecting expression
```

What does "expecting expression" mean?

Answer (score 5):

This syntax:

```
if v.(type) == map[string]interface{} { /* ... */ }
```

is invalid. You can't compare to a type, only to a value.

What you want may be solved using a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements), where the cases are indeed types:

```
func arrayReturn(m map[string]interface{}) []interface{} {
    for _, v := range m {
        switch v2 := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            return arrayReturn(v2)     // v2 is of type map[string]interface{}
        case []interface{}:
            return v2                  // v2 is of type []interface{}
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Also note that if you use a short variable declaration after the `switch` keyword, in each `case` the type of the variable used will be what you specify in the `case`, so no further type assertion is needed!